# Lambert series and higher order derivatives of the Euler Function

Tags: analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

It is well known that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n q^n}{1-q^n} = -q \frac{d}{dq} \Phi(q)$$

Where $\Phi$ is defined as follows for $|q|<1$:

$$\Phi(q) = \prod_{n=1}^\infty (1-q^n)$$

1. Is there any similar expression that showcases any type of relationship between $\Phi(q)$ and:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{q^n}{1-q^n}$$

?

2. Is there any related result (expressing the Lamber series in terms of $\Phi$) for an integer $\alpha > 1$ in:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^\alpha q^n}{1-q^n}$$

?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sums of the form $\sum\frac{n^{\alpha} q^n} {1-q^n}$ for odd positive integer $\alpha$ can always be expressed as in terms of similar sums where $\alpha=1,3,5$. Further all these are connected to $\Phi$ and its derivatives

Comment: Ramanujan wrote a paper on these sums and I have described his paper in my blog posts https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/05/certain-lambert-series-identities-and-their-proof-via-trigonometry-part-1.html?m=0 and https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/05/certain-lambert-series-identities-and-their-proof-via-trigonometry-part-2.html?m=0

Comment: Thank you very much! That post is useful, since it is *half* of what I was looking for. What about even values of $\alpha$? And is anything known about the specific case when $\alpha=0$?

Comment: You might wish to have a look at the Fourier expansions of Eisenstein series